# Control whether Windows command line commands run in new window

Tags: windows, command-line, window

In my Windows command prompt, sometimes when I run a command it gets executed in a new command prompt instead of the current one. Is there a way to control this (force commands to always run in current window or always in a new prompt)?

Example: running ipython.exe opens the interpreter in a new prompt (and i've seen this behavior with few other commands which I can't recall right now).

Comment: Can you please provide examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two types of Windows applications, console based and window based.  This is set by the developer before compiling the code.  CMD.EXE is console based, NOTEPAD.EXE is window based.  If a console based app is launched from cmd.exe, it will always open in the same window unless you do something to change that (like use the START command).  If an app opens in a new window, then it is either window based or the program itself was coded to create a new window.

Answer (score 1):

If the program itself opens a new console window, there is nothing you can do to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to resurrect such an old post, but I had a similar issue and came accross this thread, which didn't solve my problem since my .exe is definitely of the console variety. So I wanted to add my update for others.

My issue was the .exe I was calling had been configured to run elevated. The cmd prompt I was launching from was not running as an admin and it can't be elevated after it has started. So it would launch a new elevated window to run the command, which would complete in the blink of an eye and then exit leaving me with my non-elevated prompt with no output.

Solution A: Run cmd/powershell as administrator. Then it can run within the same window.
Solution B: Change the .exe to not run as administrator so it doesn't need to launch a new elevated window. This is the option I went with.

Hope that helps someone