# How can I prevent a command run in cmd from opening a new cmd window OR how can I keep that window open?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I want to run some commands from a cmd window. Currently, they open a new cmd window which closes immediately. This is unfortunate, because I would like to read the output of those commands. I have no control over the commands themselves as they are not a .bat or .cmd, they are another software's command line interface.

I know there are LOTS of questions about how to keep a cmd window open, but I fail to see how they apply to my case: I can't insert any `pause` commands, and I can't run the command with `cmd /K`. So what I need is either a way to keep the window open (which apparently is not possible, according to an answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/306167/how-to-prevent-the-command-prompt-from-closing-after-execution)), or alternatively to force the execution of the command in the window I have open. The second alternative is allegedly impossible as well, according to an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/244392/control-whether-windows-command-line-commands-run-in-new-window).

So I'm hoping there is something I've overlooked. Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I got it. The problem was that my cmd did not have administrative privileges, which is why Windows needed my confirmation to start a new window with those. Starting the first cmd as admin resolved the problem, the commands now run inside my window.

Thanks anyway, and I hope this may still help someone else.